# Related record ID in Aura Component with out server side controller (apex)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am trying to create a Aura component that fires the create new page with the default values. I am calling the Aura Component from the Quick action where I can get the the record ID but how I can get the associated ID of the record in the component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions,force:hasRecordI">
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
</aura:component>
```

Client Side Controller

```
({
 invoke : function(component, event, helper){
   var CalibrationID =  component.get("v.recordId"); 

   var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

   createRecordEvent.setParams({ 
     "entityApiName": "QA_Review__c", 
     "defaultFieldValues": {
      'QA_Calibration__c' : CalibrationID,
       'Agent__c': xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
       'Type__c': "Test",
       'Case__c': xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    } 
  });
  createRecordEvent.fire(); 
 }
```

})

Where Agent__c and Case__c are related(lookup) records

[image]

Since I have the record ID is it possible to get the associated/ related record IDs Agent__c and Case__c that is assocaited with the record ID without making a server side call.

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least SOME communication with the server, but at least you won't have to write any code yourself.

You can use the aura `recordData` component (or even the lwc version if you want).

You would write something like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="obj" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleObj" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="objError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="objRecordLoader"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="Agent__c,CaseNumber__c"
    targetRecord="{!v.obj}"
    targetFields="{!v.simpleObj}"
    targetError="{!v.objError}"
    recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
/>
```

As soon as your recordId becomes filled (which I note has a typo in your code at the top - `force:hasRecordI` is missing the `D`, then your target fields will be come filled and you can then prefill your desired record.

However, you will need to wait until the record loads, so you would **NOT** use the `invoke` method... which is **ONLY** for lwc components.

When `handleRecordUpdated` is invoked, you would then fire the `createRecordEvent`.

eg:

```
handleRecordUpdated : function(component, event, helper){
   let calibrationID =  component.get("v.recordId"); 
   let createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");

   createRecordEvent.setParams({ 
     "entityApiName": "QA_Review__c", 
     "defaultFieldValues": {
      'QA_Calibration__c' : calibrationID,
       'Agent__c': component.get("v.simpleObj.Agent__c"),
       'Type__c': "Test",
       'Case__c': component.get("v.simpleObj.CaseNumber__c")
    } 
  });
  createRecordEvent.fire(); 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.. how can this be used in the controller ?